# what should i pass as offset and limit parameters to getFile method in telegram core api?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I want to download a picture file by calling `getFile` method and this is my code using [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) (a telegram client api):

```
def get_file_req(client, volume_id, local_id, secret):
    input_file_location = InputFileLocation(volume_id, local_id, secret)
    downloaded_file = client(GetFileRequest(input_file_location, 4000, 2000))
    return downloaded_file

print(get_file_req(client, 434327164, 120080, 1200912808185991895))
```

I don't know what parameters should i pass to `GetFileRequest` method. Based on [this link](https://core.telegram.org/api/files#downloading-files), `GetFileRequest` gives `location`, `offset` and `limit` as parameters and mentioned that offset must divisible by 1KB but there is not a good example that shows what parameters should i pass to this method. When i call this method i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tclient.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(get_file_req(client, 434327164, 120080, 1200912808185991895))
  File "tclient.py", line 23, in get_file_req
    downloaded_file = client(GetFileRequest(input_file_location, 4000, 2000))
  File "C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\projects\telegram bot dev branch\myenv\Lib\site-packages\telethon\telegram_bare_client.py", line 429, in __call__
    sender, call_receive, update_state, *requests
  File "C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\projects\telegram bot dev branch\myenv\Lib\site-packages\telethon\telegram_bare_client.py", line 517, in _invoke
    raise next(x.rpc_error for x in requests if x.rpc_error)
telethon.errors.rpc_error_list.OffsetInvalidError: (OffsetInvalidError(...), 'The given offset was invalid, it must be divisible by 1KB. See https://core.telegram.org/api/files#downloading-files')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best example to download files using `telethon` is `telegram_bare_client.py`. Take a look at it [here](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/ef794bf75dd00b73cf12c85ec3a0880088dcfa82/telethon/telegram_bare_client.py).

This is the method you should be interested in:

```
def download_file(self,
                  input_location,
                  file,
                  part_size_kb=None,
                  file_size=None,
                  progress_callback=None):
```

Scroll down or search and find it. It's a big function which calls many other self-defined functions, so I don't copy the code here.

Comment: Thank you Ali! I'm trying to get a result from download_file method, but what should i pass as a file parameter to this method? I passed `open('image', 'wb')` and even `'image'` as the file parameter , but got this error : `TypeError: download_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file'`. Could you give me some example please?

Comment: `file` should be either a path or a file instance. Looks like you're passing the right argument. Can you post the line you call it?

Comment: Yep! The problem has been solved Ali! My code is :


```downloaded_file = client.download_file(input_file_location, open('image.jpg', 'wb'), part_size_kb=None, file_size=None, progress_callback=None)```